# I have two custom controls in my XAML, how can i bind one of the controls to another control?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am trying to bind a Xamarin.Forms view into another custom control through XAML, where they are both presented.

XAML:

```
 <controls:CustomThemeChanger StartImage ="{Binding StartImage}"
                      EndImage ="{Binding EndImage}"
                      x:Name = "item" />

 <controls:CustomGrid TheStartText ="{Binding Text}"
                      CustomThemeChanger="{Binding ., Source={x:Reference item}}" />
```

Code behind on the 2nd grid which wants access the first view:

```
 public CustomThemeChanger CustomThemeChanger
 {
     get { return (CustomThemeChanger)GetValue(CustomThemeChangerProperty); }
     set { SetValue(CustomThemeChangerProperty, value); }
 }

 public static readonly BindableProperty CustomThemeChangerProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomThemeChanger), typeof(CustomThemeChanger), typeof(CustomGrid), null, BindingMode.OneWay);
```

Right now it is not binding anything (null). I can bind the "TheStartText" successfully, so code seems to be fine, where as the issue seems to be in the XAML where i try to get the view.

Comment: Had a typo. Updated queston: Binding the "CustomThemeChanger" of course, but as stated in the text. It turns out to be null

Comment: Try use `{Binding ElementName=item}`. At least that's how you would do it in WPF XAML. I guess (or at least hope) it's the same in Xamarin.

Comment: "Property ElementName was not found in in type "BindingExtension""

Comment: Why are you binding with a custom control?! try to bind only what you need. binding a whole view for just fiew properties isn't something good